# Ionic 1 and Ionic 2 side by side?

Tags: ionic2

I have a project built on Ionic 1 that I need to continue to develop and support.  I'd also like to install Ionic RC2 and begin a new project with that.  Can I run both versions of Ionic on the same development machine?

Comment: Oh wait -  I guess I can install Ionic2 in my local project and leave ionic 1 installed globally.

Comment: Never mind - I missed the version switch on the cli.  You can upgrade the global instance and it just works.  use --v2 to create ionic 2 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

If you run '`ionic-serve`' in your first project folder, the default port to access it should be `8100`. If you run another '`ionic-serve`' in your ionic2 project folder, the default port to access should be `8101`.

This way you can have your ionic1 project : `localhost:8100`, and your ionic2 project on `localhost:8101`.

The same CLI is used in both cases ;-)